# Comparing two models in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have the table `item_list` and the table `users`

I have the pivot table `allowed_items` that contains `item_id` from the item_list and `user_id` from the user table.

I have some checkbox list that should be checked when the item and the user are in the pivot table, and be left unchecked if it does not.

I am currently doing this:

```
$items = item_list::all();
$allowed_items = allowed_items->where("user_id",$user_id")->get();
foreach ($allowed_item as $allow)
{
$allow_array[$allow->item_id] = true;
}
```

Then I return the view and check if the item exists like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<input type="checkbox" value="{{$item->id}} 
{{array_key_exists($item->id,$allow_array") ? "checked":" "}}>
@endforeach
```

This works, but it feels unprofessional. Any way to do this in the controller?

Comment: FYI doing this in the controller is unprofessional either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a cleaner code you can make into the Item controller a new method call e.g. isAllowed which will return a boolean function.

**Item controller**

```
public function isAllowed(){
// check if exists and return yes/no
}
```

**Template**

```
@foreach($items as $item)
   <input type="checkbox" value="{{$item->id}} 
   {{$item->isAllowed() ? "checked":" "}}>
@endforeach
```

If you can give us more details I'll edit my answer to properly answer your question.

Comment: I'd suggest using the returned collection instead to filter or  map the result.

Comment: It's not returning the collection, it's checking if the entry exists in the pivot table and will return a boolean value